# How to complete "If They Came To Hear Me Beg" Achievement

Tags: achievements, halo-reach

What level and where can I complete [If They Came To Hear Me Beg](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/halo-reach/achievement/42337-If-They-Came-To-Hear-Me-Beg.html) Halo:Reach Achievement?

> Performed an Assassination against an
>   Elite to survive a fall that would've
>   been fatal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of guides available on True Achievements for this achievement:

http://www.trueachievements.com/a60869/if-they-came-to-hear-me-beg-achievement.htm?showguides=1

Ripped from there it appears you do this on the level Pillar of Autumn.

Comment: As mentioned on TA there are other places you can get it too, but the start of Pillar of Autumn is probably the easiest to get to as it's right at the start of the level. The important thing is not to give up if you don't get it right away, it took me 30 minutes of trying before I got it right!

Comment: If you watch the Insider Moves on Halo Reach from around when the game came out (mid September 2010), that has a great guide of how to do it (that's how I got the achievement).